# converting epoch to ZonedDateTime in Java

Tags: java, epoch, datetime-conversion, zoneddatetime

How to convert epoch like `1413225446.92000` to `ZonedDateTime` in java?

The code given expects **long** value hence this will throw `NumberFormatException` for the value given above.

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(dateInMillis)), ZoneId.of(TIME_ZONE_PST));
```

Comment: PST time zone? Beware of those three (and four) letter time zone abbreviations, they are ambiguous and often not true time zones. Philippine Standard Time, Pacific Standard Time or Pitcairn Standard Time? Instead give time zone as for example America/Vancouver, that is *region/city*.

Comment: I agree @Ole. In my code TIME_ZONE_PST refers to America/Los_Angeles

Comment: That is good, Sajin Surendran. I suggest renaming, though, since for most of the year Los Angeles is at PDT, not PST.

Comment: Sajin Surendran, it’s probably no longer of interest, only in case you were curious: I thought of a different way of solving your task and edited my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time can directly parse your string

Edit: If your millisecond value is always non-negative, the following `DateTimeFormatter` can parse it.

```
private static final String TIME_ZONE_PST = "America/Los_Angeles";
private static final DateTimeFormatter epochFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS, 1, 19, SignStyle.NEVER)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
        .optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter()
        .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIME_ZONE_PST));
```

Now parsing into a `ZonedDateTime` is just one method call:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateInMillis, epochFormatter);
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

Output is:

> 2014-10-13T11:37:26.920-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

It will not work correctly with a negative value: the fraction would still be parsed as positive, which I am assuming would be incorrect. To be sure to be notified in case of a negative value I have specified in the formatter that the number cannot be signed.

### A more general solution: use BigDecimal

If you need a more general solution, for example including negative numbers, I think it’s best to let `BigDecinmal` parse the number and do the math.

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(dateInMillis);
    BigDecimal[] wholeAndFractional = bd.divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
    long seconds = wholeAndFractional[0].longValueExact();
    int nanos = wholeAndFractional[1].movePointRight(9).intValue();
    ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanos)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of(TIME_ZONE_PST));
```

Output is the same as before. Only now we can also handle negative numbers according to expectations:

```
    String dateInMillis = "-1.5";
```

> 1969-12-31T15:59:58.500-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Even scientific notation is accepted:

```
    String dateInMillis = "1.41322544692E9";
```

> 2014-10-13T11:37:26.920-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

If finer precision than nanoseconds is possible in the string, consider how you want to truncate or round, and instruct `BigDecimal` accordingly, there are a number of options.

### Original answer

[Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47975259/5772882) is a good one. Taking out the nanoseconds from the fractional part into an integer for nanoseconds may entail a pitfall or two. I suggest:

```
    String dateInMillis = "1413225446.92000";
    String[] secondsAndFraction = dateInMillis.split("\\.");
    int nanos = 0;
    if (secondsAndFraction.length > 1) { // there’s a fractional part
        // extend fractional part to 9 digits to obtain nanoseconds
        String nanosecondsString
                = (secondsAndFraction[1] + "000000000").substring(0, 9);
        nanos = Integer.parseInt(nanosecondsString);
        // if the double number was negative, the nanos must be too
        if (dateInMillis.startsWith("-")) {
            nanos = -nanos;
        } 
    }
    ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant
            .ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong(secondsAndFraction[0]), nanos)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Manila"));
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

This prints

```
2014-10-14T02:37:26.920+08:00[Asia/Manila]
```

We don’t need 64 bits for the nanoseconds, so I am just using an `int`.

Assumption: I have assumed that your string contains a floating-point number and that it may be signed, for example `-1.50` would mean one and a half seconds *before* the epoch. If one day your epoch time comes in scientific notation (1.41322544692E9), the above will not work.

Please substitute your desired time zone in the *region/city* format if it didn’t happen to be Asia/Manila, for example America/Vancouver, America/Los_Angeles or Pacific/Pitcairn. Avoid three letter abbreviations like PST, they are ambiguous and often not true time zones.

Comment: You might as well use a 64-bit `long` for the nanos. The argument to `Instant.ofEpochSecond` is passed as such.

Comment: Well, that wastes a few bits, since nanos is stored as an **int**, and is never > 999_999_999. 
    But anyway, as far as the solution here, one minor correction on handling negatives: you do not want `nanos = -nanos`, because the nanos arg is an offset adjustment, and if you send it in as negative, you adjust the epoch seconds, when you want to set nanos. [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-)

Comment: Thanks @michaelok for your comment and answer. Your answer is correct under your assumptions. Mine is under my assumptions. Which assumptions are correct only the OP can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Split the number into a pair of 64-bit long integers:

- Number of whole seconds since the epoch reference date of first moment of 1970 in UTC
- A number of nanoseconds for the fractional second

Pass those numbers to the factory method [`Instant.ofEpochSecond​(long epochSecond, long nanoAdjustment)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-)

With an `Instant` in hand, proceed to assign a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Basil's and Ole's answers here, for the special case of a **negative** timestamp i.e. before epoch. Is that even possible? Here's what [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) writes in "All about java.util.Date":

> The Date class uses “milliseconds since the Unix epoch” – that’s the
>   value returned by getTime(), and set by either the Date(long)
>   constructor or the setTime() method. As the moon walk occurred before
>   the Unix epoch, the value is negative: it’s actually -14159020000.

The only real difference between Ole's answer (besides a few extra asserts) is that here, we do not reverse the sign on nanos if the date string starts with a negative sign. The reason for this is, when passing the nanos to the [Instant constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-), that is an *adjustment*, so if we send the nanos as a negative, it will actually adjust the seconds back, and thus the entire ZonedDateTime value is off by the nanos.

This is from the JavaDoc, note the interesting behavior:

> This method allows an arbitrary number of nanoseconds to be passed in.
>   The factory will alter the values of the second and nanosecond in
>   order to ensure that the stored nanosecond is in the range 0 to
>   999,999,999. For example, the following will result in the exactly the
>   same instant:
>
> Instant.ofEpochSecond(3, 1);
>     Instant.ofEpochSecond(4,-999_999_999);
>     Instant.ofEpochSecond(2, 1000_000_001);

So the 2nd argument, nanos, we are not setting the value, it is an adjustment. So just the same as for a positive timestamp (after epoch), we want to send in the actual nanos.

Taking Ole's code as a base and adding the above mentioned changes:

```
    String strDateZoned = "Jul 20 1969 21:56:20.599 CDT"; // yes, should use America/Chicago here as Ole points out
    DateTimeFormatter dtfFormatter  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
    ZonedDateTime     originalZoned  = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateZoned, dtfFormatter);

    long epochSeconds = originalZoned.toInstant().getEpochSecond();
    int nanoSeconds = originalZoned.toInstant().getNano();
    String dateInMillis = epochSeconds + "." + nanoSeconds;
    String[] secondsAndFraction = dateInMillis.split("\\.");
    int nanos = 0;
    if (secondsAndFraction.length > 1) { // there’s a fractional part
        // extend fractional part to 9 digits to obtain nanoseconds
        String nanosecondsString
                = (secondsAndFraction[1] + "000000000").substring(0, 9);
        nanos = Integer.parseInt(nanosecondsString);
    }

    ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant
            .ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong(secondsAndFraction[0]), nanos)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));

    String formattedZdt = dtfFormatter.format(zdt);

    System.out.println("zoneDateTime expected    = " + strDateZoned);
    System.out.println("zoneDateTime from millis = " + formattedZdt);

    assertEquals("date in millis is wrong",  "-14159020.599000000", dateInMillis);
    assertEquals("date doesn't match expected",strDateZoned, dtfFormatter.format(zdt));
```

Output from code:

```
zoneDateTime expected    = Jul 20 1969 21:56:20.599 CDT
zoneDateTime from millis = Jul 20 1969 21:56:20.599 CDT
```

If we reverse the sign on nanos for the case where the seconds part is negative, we can see the difference in the formatted ZonedDateTime:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: date doesn't match expected 
Expected :Jul 20 1969 21:56:20.599 CDT
Actual   :Jul 20 1969 21:56:19.401 CDT
```

P.S. A few more thoughts from the 'All About Dates' post on what Jon Skeet calls "leniency", and elsewhere I have seen called 'normalization' which is perhaps due to POSIX influences:

> It’s lenient for no obvious reason: “In all cases, arguments given to
>   methods for these purposes need not fall within the indicated ranges;
>   for example, a date may be specified as January 32 and is interpreted
>   as meaning February 1.” How often is that useful?