# java.time.Instant does not render on the consumer side

Tags: java, timestamp, spring-kafka, java-time, java.time.instant

I am trying to send some information with Kafka. I have a class to handle this task. The class includes a private variable called "timestamp" of type Instant. When the timestamp is generated, it renders correctly. However, when I receive the message on the consumer side, the time stamp is not readable.

It looks like this `"timestamp": 1685968244.889278400`

Additionally, I have a response class defined as follows:

```java
public class Response<T> {
    private T data;
    private String statusCode;
    private String statusMessage;
    private Instant timestamp;
}
```

When I converted `timestamp` atribute to String, everything looks well but I want to render the timestamp as below:
`"timestamp": 2023-06-05T15:07:06.497159Z`
How can I do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting epoch to ZonedDateTime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975195/converting-epoch-to-zoneddatetime-in-java)

Comment: Try to add this dependency on both sides: `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-modules-java8`. So, Jackson will serialize and deserialiaze Java time objects properly: https://learnersbucket.com/examples/java/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper/

Comment: @OleV.V. unfortunately that's not the answer for me

Comment: @ArtemBilan this dependency already included but when I use that dependency for deserialize, the API is failing. Therefore, I need to use `JsonDeserializer` from `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer`

Comment: So, does it work or not? That `JsonDeserializer` relies on a `JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper()` by default which does this `registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(objectMapper);` including the mentioned `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule`. Therefore I'm not sure in your comment.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Sorry for confusing. When I use `JsonDeserializer` from `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer` API is able to run but the output is like this: `"timestamp": 1685968244.889278400`. When I use `JsonDeserializer` from `com.fasterxml.jackson` even API is not able to run. It's failing while API is building

Comment: That's correct. We talk exactly about `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer`. That dependency must be there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect from Instant type. Once, I had the same problem and I fixed that when I replace Instant with DateTime from Joda-Time. Another possible solution is if you are using a custom serializer/deserializer that might occur too. So, basically, you can use JsonSerializer/JsonDeserializer. I wish this information will work for you

Comment: Thanks, that works. I wanted give you +1 but I couldn't because of my reputation

Comment: No worries. I am glad that help to you

Comment: Which `DateTime` type is that? From Joda-Time???